# Pandas - A merge operation that merges common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe both has columns : **url**, **title**
I want to merge them using left join on url column, but I want operation to not create different columns (*title_x*, *title_y*) and Instead create a **single title** column
Should I approach join here or `np.where()` like method

I tried this but I think it's not a good approach to solve the problem :

```
test = main.merge(df, how = 'left', on = 'url')
test['title'] = np.where(test.title_x.isna(), test.title_y, test.title_x)
test.drop(columns = ['title_x', 'title_y'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column name in df to consider only the columns you want like this:

```
test = main.merge(df['url'], how='left', on='url')
```

This will consider only 'url' column from df and prevent _x and _y even if you have more columns with same names in both dataframes.